# flutter app release apk does not open camera

Tags: flutter, camera, android-camera

I have a flutter app which uses the phone's camera. While debugging I can successfully use the camera but when using a release apk I have built I get a blank screen. I have added the permissions to the manifest and also the app requests for user to grant permission too.

Here is how it looks in debug mode

[image: Debug Screenshot]

Here is how it looks when I install app-release.apk

[image: Release screenshot]

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. I was using an expanded widget in a stack. So when I run the app in debug mode I can open and use the camera, However if the app is in release mode it shows the white screen. Hence, I removed the epanded widget and only the stack widget.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need

```
flutter clean
```

(I'd consider it a bug that this is necessary, but I'm encountering it as well)
and

```
flutter build apk --release
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you ask the user for permission?
If not the system will block all camera requests

Comment: check permission on setting of the device too